# Search with SQL statement and OR operator

Tags: sql-server

Hello everyone I need to make a search, by telling the user, either make a search by name, or price

```
SELECT        
   BID.BiddingPrice, BID.Date, Item.Name
FROM            
   BID 
INNER JOIN
   Buyer ON BID.BuyerID = Buyer.BuyerID 
INNER JOIN
   Member ON Buyer.MemberID = Member.MemberID 
INNER JOIN
   Auction ON BID.AuctionID = Auction.AuctionID 
INNER JOIN
   Item ON Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID
WHERE        
   (Auction.Status = 'Expired') 
   AND (BID.Date BETWEEN @from AND @to) 
   OR (BID.Status = 'Available') 
   OR (Member.Username = @username) 
   OR (BID.BiddingPrice = @price) 
   OR (Item.Name = @name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have highlighted the changes I think are required to achieve the results you are looking for. You will need to pass the value of price or name depending on what the user has supplied and NULL for the other value. For example, name = 'Ron', price = NULL.

```
SELECT        BID.BiddingPrice, BID.Date, Item.Name
FROM            BID INNER JOIN
                     Buyer ON BID.BuyerID = Buyer.BuyerID INNER JOIN
                     Member ON Buyer.MemberID = Member.MemberID INNER JOIN
                     Auction ON BID.AuctionID = Auction.AuctionID INNER JOIN
                     Item ON Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID
WHERE        (Auction.Status = 'Expired') AND (BID.Date BETWEEN @from AND @to) **AND**
                     (BID.Status = 'Available') **AND**
                     (Member.Username = @username) **AND**
                     **CASE WHEN @Price IS NOT NULL THEN
                         (BID.BiddingPrice = @price) ELSE
                         (Item.Name = @name) 
                     END**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BID.BiddingPrice, BID.Date, Item.Name
FROM  BID 
INNER JOIN Buyer ON BID.BuyerID = Buyer.BuyerID 
INNER JOIN Member ON Buyer.MemberID = Member.MemberID 
INNER JOIN Auction ON BID.AuctionID = Auction.AuctionID 
INNER JOIN Item ON Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID
WHERE        
Auction.Status = 'Expired'
AND (BID.Date BETWEEN @from AND @to)
OR BID.Status = 'Available' 
OR Member.Username = @username
OR(
   (Item.Name = @name OR  @name is null) 
OR (BID.BiddingPrice = @price OR  @price is null)
)
```

In case if any @parameter can be null then you should create your where clause like:

```
 WHERE        
    Auction.Status = 'Expired'
    AND (BID.Date>= @from OR @from is null) 
    AND (BID.Date<= @to OR @to IS NULL)
    OR BID.Status = 'Available' 
    OR (Member.Username = @username OR @username is null) 
    OR(
       (Item.Name = @name OR  @name is null) 
    OR (BID.BiddingPrice = @price OR  @price is null)
    )
```

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in my question it was to make a search even if some values are not supplied

Comment: are you sure for that it work even if the user doesn't supplied the some values?

Comment: Yes for: (Member.Username = _username OR _username is null) two cases if _username has value condition is true OR if _username is null also  condition is true. (_username means @username bcoz in comment only one AtTheRate sign allowed)

Comment: 0 OR 1 = 1 ::::: 1 OR 0 = 1 ---------------Good night

Answer (score 0):

While this can be done in a static query by cleverly "turning on and off" parts of the WHERE clause (as other answers have shown), please beware of potential performance implications of doing so - the DBMS may not be able to produce the optimal query plan.

This is one of these occasions where [dynamic SQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/myth-directory/dynamic-sql-is-slow) may be more appropriate. Using dynamic SQL does not mean you should stop using bound parameters though!